# Add two parameters to href within jQuery Template using MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, actionresult

I am hoping I have given enough information for someone to help.
(I have cut out the bits of code that I felt were not relevant)

I have a jquery template, inside of which is a link that returns an id to an ActionResult.
My question is: what is the syntax for adding another parameter to the link so the ActionResult receives two parameters.

```
<script id="searchTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <a href="/Search/Details/${JournalId} WHAT GOES HERE?    ">
</script>

 public ActionResult Details(int id, string otherParameter)
    {
      var item = ctx.Journals.Find(id);
      return View("Details", item);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script id="searchTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
  <a href="/Search/Details/${JournalId}?otherParameter=value">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that will work, but the "best practices" way in MS MVC is to create a new Route in the Global.asax.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
// callable like this: <a href="/Search/Details/${JournalId}/value"> 
routes.MapRoute(
            "MyNewRouteName",
            "MyController/SomeCoolAction/{id}/{otherParameter}",
            new { controller = "MyController", action = "SomeCoolAction"}
            );

....
}
```